# Hard Drive Failure - Next Steps and Process

Tags: hard-drive, smart, bad-sectors, hard-drive-failure, disk-cloning

I have a 2TB Barracuda that has some bad sectors (detected via CrystalDiskInfo). When I turned on my computer, I cannot detect my D:, E:, F:... which are all mapped to my failed disk. What I mean is that I don't see my missing partitions when I go to 'This PC':
[image: A screenshot of Windows Explorer showing available drives C: and K:]

Here is the latest report from last year on CrystalDisk when I first noticed the bad sectors. Since last year, the bad sector count has not increased.
[image: Screenshot from CrystalDiskInfo. Disk's status is indicated as "Caution". Current Pending Sector Count and Uncorrectable Sector Count are marked as needing attention.]

Unfortunately I have a lot of software and data mapped to this failed drive. Installation of the software will be a pain, and I didn't back up this month's data. I am wondering what alternatives do I have in recovering my hard drive?

My first thought is that I should somehow clone my hard drive. If I am to do so, would the software clone the drive exactly (ie - even clone the partitions)? Would I need to use another healthy hard drive that is exactly the same size (2TB)? What happens when the cloning software encounters an unhealthy sector?

I also noticed that Windows 10 is taking an extremely long time to restart/shut-down. I have Windows 10 installed on a SSD and it normally takes < 15 seconds to restart/shut-down. Now it is taking several minutes. Is this because Windows is trying resolve something on the missing/failed drive?

Update - I have unplugged my failed drive and Windows has been loading within 15 seconds (my OS is installed on my SSD).

Comment: **Stop using the drive right now.** Doing anything with a failing drive - even powering it on - can cause more damage. If you don't want to lose your data or make it harder to recover, power off the computer right now and unplug the drive completely.

Comment: @gronostaj - What should my next steps be?

Comment: As a general suggestion, once you are prepared with a new drive (idealy of equal size if possible), you should transfer any data off the failing drive ASAP. You likely want to investigate using a Linux Live CD with DDRescue (which deals well with bad drives/sectors), though you want to probably do some homework before using it. Trinity Rescue Kit might be a good option since it is aimed at Windows recovery - - http://trinityhome.org/Home/index.php?content=TRINITY_RESCUE_KIT____CPR_FOR_YOUR_COMPUTER&front_id=12&lang=en&locale=en

Comment: @Anaksunaman How do I transfer the data off my failing drive? When I go to 'This PC', Windows 10 does not see the missing partitions.

Comment: Apologies. You want to boot with the Linux Live CD and use the tools it provides (such as DDRescue or similar) to copy data. It isn't guaranteed that the live CD will be able to work with the disk, but (anecdotally) it is more likely the live CD will be able to see and work with the data/partitions/etc. than Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HD Clone was able to clone all but my failed partition to another drive. Note that the trial version supports up to 2TB disk clones.

Answer (score -1):

As long as the drive is still functional I have had great success just cloning the failing drive on to a new drive using Clonezilla.